# How to sort multiple rows in Excel and how to tell Excel that two rows are one

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I want to sort this sheet by party name but the problem is, I want to sort both rows by party name and in ascending order. b2 and b3 are the elements of the partyname, so I want to sort both rows on party name. Is there any way other than VBA to sort on multiple columns?

UNSORTED

[image: 1]

SORTED

[image: 2]

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking and what do the pictures represent. Do you mean [Multiple Criteria Sort](http://glencoe.mheducation.com/sites/0078612357/student_view0/unit5/enrichment_activity_5_2.html)?

Comment: @AryeShemesh Each entry has two rows. Row 2 and 3 is one entry, 4 and 5 is one. If I understand it correct

Comment: @AryeShemesh correct

Comment: @AryeShemesh no wait row 3 and 4 are one, 5 and 6 are one,

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Vinit. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly then this might be a solution for you. Why don't you use a pivot table & data set?  It will be more easy to handle data.

[image: PivotTable and Data Set]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a helper column which looks at odd and even rows and combines your column B values into a sortable list.

In a new column add this formula: `=IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=1,$B3 & $B4, $B2 & $B3)`
Odd rows are the Party Name, even rows are the C.Bill.No.

If you're on an odd row then show that row and the following row, of you're on an even row show the previous row and that row.

[image]